# Debian and Centos: why does ipv6 prevail over ipv4

Tags: debian, centos, ipv6, ipv4

Every time I am configuring a Debian or Centos machine with a static IP address, I forget about that behavior of not taking in account my IPV4 configuration. Then, I search for the 1000th time the parameter to put in `sysctl.conf` to disable IPV6, and finally I reboot the beast.

- An example to illustrate :

  `Linux deb-router 3.2.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.2.81-2 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

It has 2 interfaces; eth0 is configured in IPV4 for some time (1 year maybe).

ETH1 is bridged on my physical network and was addressed by the DHCP, in IPV4. I talk to the VM through this interface.

Tonight I lost my Internet gateway; this device is also my DHCP server.

I realized I cannot reach my VM anymore, so I checked `ifconfig` and saw a nice IPV6 instead of the old IPV4 bound to ETH1.

So, action !

```
$ sudo vim /etc/network/interfaces

allow-hotplug eth1
# was dhcp before
iface eth1 inet static
    address 192.168.0.15
    netmask 255.255.255.0

$ sudo ifdown eth1 && sudo ifup eth1
```

Deception :(

`ifconfig` outputs only an ipv6; I cannot reach my VM. I must disable IPV6 (`net.ipv6.conf.eth1.disable_ipv6 = 1`), and reboot, to get the connection back.

- I don't understand this choice to favor IPV6 over IPV4:  Most of people are working with IPV4, from what I know.
- Is it technical, or is it political to influence people to adopt IPV6 ?

Comment: IPv4 and IPv6 are not mutually exclusive, it's very normal these days you have them on the same interface side by side. There is nothing wrong with that. Disabling IPv6 might even break some software. If your interface IPv4 doesn't work there is another reason because IPv6 is a different protocol and it doesn't affect your IPv4 settings.

Comment: If disabling IPv6 somehow made IPv4 work, then something else on your system is broken. No such thing actually happens alone. As for IPv6, it's preferred because it's the default protocol. If you hadn't heard, IPv4 ran out of addresses, so everyone must switch to IPv6. Many people do not even get their own IPv4 addresses anymore.

Comment: @SanderSteffann In theory I totally agree with you, from my experience I often encountered this situation, especially with a fresh Centos install. From what I remember with Debian this is the first time it happens to me. Can you demonstrate me how to concretely achieve this cohabitation between the 2 stack ? or pointing me out to a source which explain how it works ?

Comment: @MichaelHampton Yes I am aware of that penury, however during my experience in IT, I never seen anybody using it in the company I worked for. I think as usual (almost) everybody is waiting to have his back to the wall, and maybe decision makers have other priority...  Anyway, I have some concern about the fact that every Centos I deployed since  3 years, and my local VM I currently work-on are broken. Maybe I am missing something, can you demonstrate me how to concretely achieve this cohabitation between the 2 stack ? or pointing me out to a source which explain how it works ?

Comment: `/etc/gai.conf` #    For sites which prefer IPv4 connections change the last line to ` precedence ::ffff:0:0/96  100`; it could well be your IPv6 network infra-structure is broken...once here in the beginnings of the IPv6 project everything was well with the IPv4 firewall rules, but IPv6 was not that well tested.

Comment: Running dual-stack is just a matter of configuring both "iface eth1 inet static" and "iface eth1 inet6 static" in most cases.

Comment: @SanderSteffann I don't need to run dual stack, just IPv4, I re enable V6 on the machine, rebooted and now I can reach it, with the two stak indeed : 
    `eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0c:29:be:d6:fa
    inet addr:192.168.0.15  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
    inet6 addr: fe80::20c:29ff:febe:d6fa/64 Scope:Link`

My question is why in the first place, configuring a static IP, disabling and enabling the interface isn't enough to get an IPv4 back, meanwhile an IPv6 is there and i don't use it / I am not aware of IPv6 packet flowing through my computer, it's annoying,

Comment: The address `fe80::20c:29ff:febe:d6fa` is a link-local address. Every interface has one, and it's only usable on your local LAN. It's not a routable IPv6 address. Why your IPv4 wasn't working: no idea, sounds like a bug somewhere. The information you provide is not enough to determine the cause. But having IPv6 enabled isn't it, that assumption is almost certainly wrong.

Comment: Install Debian, and _don't_ do anything to try to disable IPv6. It will work. I have no idea what state your current system is in, or how it got that way, so I couldn't begin to guess how to get it out of that state. I would check the documentation on how the server was configured, to see what was done to it.

Comment: I've found that in most cases - and this is where Michael will be right but you'll still see what you saw - the IPv6 will 'take precedence' only when the IPv4 can't be initialized. 

Case in point:  IPv4 dhcpcd isn't working or the dhcpd is down or its route and its IPs don't coexist.  IPv6 will still be initialized (unless you disable it via your sysctl [and about 4 other pieces you need to still do!])  happily and the machine will try to access the world via IPv6.  

It really smells like a survival tactic when IPv4 is lame or broken.

Answer (score 2):

ipv6 is not the problem! You are missing a line `auto eth1` in your /etc/network/interfaces in order to let `ifup eth1` work.

The reason you see an ipv6 in the ifconfig-output is that your server simply doesn't has an ipv4 because -- as you stated -- your dhcp-server went down.

`ip` is a much more useful tool than `ifconfig` (on Linux machines):

`ip -4 address` ... shows only v4 addresses
`ip -6 address` ... shows only v6 addresses